# Limpar apenas uma parte da URL

Tags: javascript

Estou usando uma função para limpar a URL, porém eu gostaria apenas de limpar uma parte da mesma.

```
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);
    }, 5000);
```

Por exemplo na URL está `?id=1&msg=sc` e eu queria deixar apenas `?id=1` como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Para que está fazendo isso? Não seria melhor apenas pegar diretamente os valores de `id` e `msg` sem ter que fazer separações e substituições?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível usando o `split`, você pode separar sua url por `&` e recuperar apenas o primeiro parâmetro.

```js
let url = "google.com?id=1&msg=sc"; // url
let urlSplit = url.split("&"); // cria um array separados por '&'
url = urlSplit[0]; // Recupera o primeiro item do array, no caso tudo antes do primeiro '&'

console.log(url);
```

Caso queira pegar mais que um parâmetro, basta concatenar os parâmetros, ficando algo dessa forma:

```js
let url = "google.com?id=1&msg=sc&teste=123"; // url
let urlSplit = url.split("&"); // cria um array separados por '&'
url = `${urlSplit[0]}&${urlSplit[2]}`; // Recupera os items do array, concatenando por &

console.log(url);
```

Comment: Implementei no meu código, no console ele funciona, mas na url do navegador permanece a url, precisaria ser feito alguma coisa para funcionar?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: `window.location.href = url`

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/URL

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href)
url.searchParams.delete("msg")
history.replaceState(history.state, null, url.toString());
```

Demonstração da ideia (Chrome 49+, FF 29+):

```js
var address = "http://google.com?id=1&msg=sc"
var url = new URL(address)
url.searchParams.delete("msg")
console.log(url.toString())
```